# Inability to use console to clipboard after using it once ?

Tags: c#, regex, console-application, clipboard

I made this real quick this morning and It worked once , and has not since. I find that really odd. The purpose is to take a string of data and parse out the emails using regEx and then I thought I don't need a file just send it to clipboard.

```
static void Main()
    {
        //string result;
        StringBuilder sbObfuscate = new StringBuilder();


        //TODO MAKE INPUT and ways to se REGEX
        string emails = "FDJSKJK<fdafda@dsa.com>, dfafjekw <2321@sds.coom> 421";
        //Reg Ex to remove the <> and gather the email .
        Regex regex2 = new Regex("(?<=<).*?(?=>)");

        foreach (Match match in regex2.Matches(
            emails))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value + ",");
            sbObfuscate.Append(match.Value + ",");
        }
        // send to clipboard a string witht he last , removed
        Clipboard.SendToWindowsClipboard(sbObfuscate.ToString().Remove(sbObfuscate.Length - 1));
    }




public class Clipboard
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool CloseClipboard();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool SetClipboardData(uint uFormat, IntPtr data);

    [STAThread]
    public static void SendToWindowsClipboard(string clipboardData)
    {
        OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero);
        var yourString = clipboardData;
        var ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(yourString);
        SetClipboardData(13, ptr);
        //The 13 passed in as the first argument is the data format. 13 means unicode string.
        CloseClipboard();
        Console.WriteLine("check");
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    }
}
```

the code seems solid and copied from stackOverflow for the most part. Why would the copy to clipboard work once and not any other time afterward ? it there something I haven't considered ?

Comment: Could you explain better what is not working? Data not present in the Clipboard? An error message?

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code ., or are you just doing the usual `code and go` meaning just copy pasting code and running it and expecting it to work flawlessly all the time without debugging it..?

Comment: it worked the first time and Has not worked since , ( yeah sort of code and go , because it did work once I made it , I did try a breakPoint and it shows the data) IDK if it is sending it to the clipboard correctly , it is not in the clipboard after I run the program.

SO I ran the program and pasted the email list to the email I needed to send. Then a few hours later when I was showing to someone else it did not work. We looked at it for a while and are confused on why it would not work a second time. ( yes I tried to restart Visual Studio, after debugging was useless )

Comment: Are you setting it to clipboard text ? For a test, just send some static text. It's never good to debug the whole thing, but to do it in steps.